# Path is not in legal form - winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, path

I have a WinForms program that works perfectly fine in debug mode but whenever I try release it spits out an error of path is not of legal form This is the [Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGynr.png)
and here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            refreshtext();
        }

        string path = Properties.Settings.Default.SavedPath;
        string pathfull;
        string selected = "";

        private void Pokeditor_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (selected == "" || path == "(default)") return;
            pathfull = path + @"\" + selected;

            if (File.Exists(pathfull + @"\y7.bin") && File.Exists(pathfull + @"\y9.bin"))
            {
                File.Move(pathfull + @"\y7.bin", pathfull + @"\arm7ovltable.bin");
                File.Move(pathfull + @"\y9.bin", pathfull + @"\arm9ovltable.bin");
                Directory.Delete(pathfull + @"\unpacked");
                MessageBox.Show("This will now work with Pokeditor");
            }
            else return;

        }

        private void DSPRE_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (selected == "" || path == "(default)") return;
            pathfull = path + @"\" + selected;
            if (File.Exists(pathfull + @"\arm7ovltable.bin") && File.Exists(pathfull + @"\arm9ovltable.bin"))
            {
                File.Move(pathfull + @"\arm7ovltable.bin", pathfull + @"\y7.bin");
                File.Move(pathfull + @"\arm9ovltable.bin", pathfull + @"\y9.bin");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathfull + @"\unpacked");
                MessageBox.Show("This will now work with DSPRE");
            }
            else return;
        }

        private void FolderBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderFinder.Description = "Find the pokeditor folder With the .pokeditor file";
            this.FolderFinder.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
            this.FolderFinder.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;

            if (this.FolderFinder.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = this.FolderFinder.SelectedPath;
                refreshtext();

            }
            Properties.Settings.Default.SavedPath = path;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        }

        private void refreshtext()
        {
            selected = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
            SelectedFolder.Text = selected;
        }
```

I've tried to change the different if statements to make it legal and searched up this error with no avail

Comment: If this is only happening in the production application and not when debugging then it's time to add some logging to the application.  When the error occurs, what is the value of `path` being used on that line of code?  Does that value match what you expect?

Comment: Presumably `Properties.Settings.Default.SavedPath` is empty when you use the release code the first time because you don't have a config yet. Debug should also fail when you delete your config you have created at somepoint while creating the application. You need code  that handles the "no configuration" situation.

Comment: The project properties (including `Settings`) are different in different configurations. When your form is launched the first time after the release is built, it will read `Properties.Settings.Default.SavedPath` as `null` or some default value (don't know exactly, but the default value is definitely not a valid path) if you, assuming that the value from debugging build will persist, don't set it to some value before compiling. **Always check if the app property you've read is valid. If it is not, do something (e.g. ask the user) to determine the valid value.**

Comment: I forgot to reply but i just made a function to check if the password is empty and then made the variable something which then made it so it worked